# Updating custom field with module upgrade gives a "Page not found"

Tags: 8, updating

I have been working for quite some time on a custom module. So far I have always been able to reinstall everything from scratch, but now I need an update to a custom field. Following the indications in [Manually Downloading Module or Theme Files](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/extend-manual-install.html) and in [Updating a Module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/security-update-module.html) I created a mymodule.install file with a content like this:

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database ;

function mymodule_update_8101(&$sandbox) {
    $spec = [
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 32,
    ) ;

    $schema = Database::getConnection()->schema();
    $schema->addField('node__field_newfield', 'column_name', $spec);
}
```

Then I put the site in maintenance mode, replaced my module directory with the new one, and then went to http://myserver:myport/update.php, which showed me the small update file as a message. I clicked on Continue, and I got a Page not found.

I am sure I am missing something trivial, but I can't understand what :(

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot of information, but you do have an error in your code,

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database ;

function mymodule_update_8101(&$sandbox) {
    $spec = [
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 32,
    ];
//    ) ;

    $schema = Database::getConnection()->schema();
    $schema->addField('node__field_newfield', 'column_name', $spec);
}
```

Comment: Oh--now I feel rather stupid :(

Unfortunately, there was a problem _before_ the one in the code, I had put Drupal in a subdirectory and, while index.php worked well, update.php loaded correctly when called without parameters, but returned a 404 when a parameter (specifically, `/selection`) was passed. I solved the first problem by moving back Drupal to root, then of course I corrected the error you pointed up, now my updates are not found, but that's a different problem...